# SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy does not work on the specific time

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing a web application where user adds issue specifying the date and time on which he/she should get a notification mail. I'm new to apache camel and quartz scheduler.

I have written a sample code as below. IssueDTO is nothing but a POJO. If the issue is repetitive, I have configured a cron scheduler which works properly i.e. if I specify frequency as 5, I get the expected output which is a println statement to the console. But if the issue is not repetitive, I have used SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy and hardcoded the date and time at which process() method of the Processor should run. I simply change the date time to 2 min later of the current system time to check whether code is working. But it never enters the process method and does print this statement => System.out.println("*****************" + issueDTO.getIssueId() + " running at " + gc.getTime().toString());

```java
 @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("in ReminderRouteBuilder configure()");
        System.out.println("Issue ID : " + issueDTO.getIssueId());
        System.out.println("Issue Frequency : " + issueDTO.getFrequency());
        System.out.println("Is Repetative : " + issueDTO.getIsRepetitive());

        // if Repetitive
        if (StringUtil.getBoolean(issueDTO.getIsRepetitive()))
        {
            String fromString = "quartz2://" + issueDTO.getIssueId() + "?cron=0/" + issueDTO.getFrequency() + "+*+*+*+*+?";
            from(fromString).process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
                {
                    System.out.println(issueDTO.getIssueId() + " running every " + issueDTO.getFrequency() + " sec...");
                }
            });
        }
        // if not Repetitive
        else
        {
            SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy policy = new SimpleScheduledRoutePolicy();
            GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.AUGUST, 31, 13, 45);
            policy.setRouteStartDate(gc.getTime());

            from("direct:start").routeId(issueDTO.getIssueId()).routePolicy(policy).process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
                {
                    System.out.println("*****************" + issueDTO.getIssueId() + " running at " + gc.getTime().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[Direct endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html) needs to be triggered manualy with some event. If you need something, what is triggered automatically after start of route, you can use [Timer endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html) with `repeatCount=1` or [Quartz endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/quartz-component.html) with `fireNow=true`.

E.g. this will trigger `Exchange` only once, after route startup:

```
from("timer:start?repeatCount=1").routeId(issueDTO.getIssueId()).routePolicy(policy)
```

Comment: i tried both ways i.e. Timer endpoint and Quartz endpoint. But in both the cases, it does respect `startDate` specified in `routePolicy`. It starts the route as soon as the this line is executed `from("timer:start?repeatCount=1").routeId(issueDTO.getIssueId()).routePolicy(policy)`. I want to trigger the event only at the specific time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I got the solution :).
I used the cron expression specifying exact date and time and it worked.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("in ReminderRouteBuilder configure()");
    System.out.println("Issue ID : " + issueDTO.getIssueId());
    System.out.println("Issue Frequency : " + issueDTO.getFrequency());
    System.out.println("Is Repetative : " + issueDTO.getIsRepetitive());

    // if Repetitive
    if (StringUtil.getBoolean(issueDTO.getIsRepetitive()))
    {
        String fromString = "quartz2://" + issueDTO.getIssueId() + "?cron=0/" + issueDTO.getFrequency() + "+*+*+*+*+?";
        from(fromString).process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
            {
                System.out.println(issueDTO.getIssueId() + " running every " + issueDTO.getFrequency() + " sec...");
            }
        });
    }
    // if not Repetitive
    else
    {
        String fromString = "quartz2://" + issueDTO.getIssueId() + "?cron=0 40 12 4 SEP ? 2019";
        from(fromString).process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
            {
                System.out.println(issueDTO.getIssueId() + " running now");
            }
        });
    }
}
```